# How to conver dmy to d-m-y in php?

Tags: php, date, time

How to convert from dmy to d-m-y, using this code, but this method is not what I want.

```
      $source = '05032020';
      $date = new DateTime($source);
      echo $date->format('d.m.Y'); // 05-03-2020
```

Comment: What format do you want? `05-03-2020` looks like it matches your `d-m-y` requirements.

Comment: i want, dd-mm-yy

Comment: Your source is not in a common format, so you're going to have to pass it through [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$source = '05032020';
$date = date_create_from_format('dmY', $source);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); //05-03-2020
```

Comment: this option is correct, I have one more question whether it is possible to make the time hi (1934) in h: i (19:34) using this method?

Comment: Try this.
$source = '1934';
$date = date_create_from_format('Hi', $source);
echo $date->format('H:i');